# Python 3 sched.scheduler timer start

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer, scheduler

Here's what we want to be able to do:

1. Schedule many calls, each for a precise number of milliseconds after we start a timer T.
2. Set something else up to run in another thread S.
3. Start thread S and start the timer T.

How can we do this?

Here's the [API reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html). We actually expected the "time units" in `scheduler.enter` to be with respect to the call to `scheduler.run`, but apparently it's with respect to **that** call to `scheduler.enter`. With enough events, that introduces a time difference between jobs scheduled at i=0 in our scheduling loop and i=10**6, let alone the time difference that setting up the thread S introduces.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always implement your own scheduler with [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html). Here's a simple example of a scheduler where the delay is relative to `start`:

```
import heapq
import time

def fun(after, s):
    print('{} after {} seconds: {}'.format(time.time(), after, s))

class Sched:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = []

    def add_task(self, delay_seconds, priority, callback, args):
        task = (delay_seconds, priority, callback, args)
        heapq.heappush(self.tasks, task)

    def start(self):
        self.start_time = time.monotonic()

        while self.tasks:
            now = time.monotonic()
            delta = now - self.start_time
            nxt = self.tasks[0][0]

            if delta < nxt:
                time.sleep(nxt - delta)
            else:
                _, _, callback, args = heapq.heappop(self.tasks)
                callback(*args)

sched = Sched()
sched.add_task(5, 1, fun, (5, 'second'))
sched.add_task(5, 0, fun, (5, 'first'))
sched.add_task(7, 0, fun, (7, 'third'))

print(time.time(), 'start')
sched.start()
print(time.time(), 'end')
```

Output:

```
1485623736.9788322 start
1485623741.9809415 after 5 seconds: first
1485623741.9809415 after 5 seconds: second
1485623743.9846892 after 7 seconds: third
1485623743.9846892 end
```

Note that the tasks are not run exactly when requested. This is because of limitations of [`sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/time.html#time.sleep) and possibly the time it takes to execute previous task.

Comment: Thanks! This is blocking though. Is sched as well? I always manage to misunderstand Python docs more than any other.

Comment: @DouglasMyers-Turnbull You can [`run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler.run) it in both modes, default it blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share the solution we actually used. I graphed a scatter plot of x=scheduled-time and y=actual-time for executions using two methods:

- using something similar to niemmi's answer, using `time.sleep`
- using a dedicated thread to poll without sleeping:

  ```
  # where queue is a DeQueue that pops the earliest scheduled time first
  r = range(0, len(self._stimulus_list))
  t0 = monotonic()
  for _ in r:
      nxt = queue.get_nowait()
      while monotonic() - t0 < t_now: pass
      nxt.execute()
  ```

The second method had a slope closer to 1.0 with an average abs error of about 1μs (though some expected bias). We sacrificed a thread completely and used the second method.

I still find the `sched` package pretty counter-intuitive.